# Dealing with "conceptual" questions

Tags: discussion, scope, on-hold

Imaging you've been programming in C# for a while, and now you just happen to need something new which you haven't yet heard about it. Say "anonymous types" or "aspect oriented programming".

Because you haven't yet heard about those concepts, how will you search the web to find them? Finally, you'll ask in a forum. How can you ask a question about such a concept, if you do not know about it? And now imagine that English is not your native language, and try...

The question will look very terrible, hard to understand, unclear etc. And what ever reasons you'll need to put them on hold. As it often happens.

Is that fair behavior?

[Now put this on hold, too.]

Comment: If the question is "very terrible, hard to understand, unclear etc" then yes, it is fair.

Comment: You have to know the rules before you play a game.Similarly,you have to know a bit about SO before posting.

Comment: This is NOT a "forum"

Answer (score 10):

With a reputation of +20, you can use the chatrooms on the site.

I think that would be a better place to ask essentially a meta-question  (e.g. *"what's that thing called with pointcuts again, can't remember the name of it & trying to Google for more info"*).

Answer (score 8):

While it doesn't absolve you from writing a clear, well thought out question we have a site for conceptual questions:

> [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Where your question (provided it's a good, clear, well thought out question) will be welcome - a whole lot more welcome than on Stack Overflow.

Searching there for the terms you *have* got may well find questions and answers that help you - if not completely then at least enough to be able to write that good, clear, well thought out question.

Go on, give it a try. You might like it.